# SQL avg function in partition by

Tags: sql, window-functions

I have a task to count average-value of 3 columns in a section of 3 criteria.

This is a source-table:

[image]

I need to select average values of primary needs, working or leisure, grouped by the different ages of life (young, active or elder), sex and working status.

For this purpose I apply the following query with window-function:

```
SELECT
    working, sex, age, 
    ROUND(AVG(primaryNeeds) OVER(w),1) primaryNeeds,
    ROUND(avg(work) OVER(w),1) work,
    ROUND(avg(other)OVER(w),1) other
FROM 
    demography
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY 'age', 'working', 'sex' ORDER BY 'age', 'working', 'sex')
```

But in the resulting selection average values counted without grouping by 'age', 'working', 'sex' - columns.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please avoid data as image. you can create/format a table using `|`.

Comment: `PARTITION BY X ORDER BY X` doesn't make a whole heap of sense - by *definition*, you know all rows within a partition share the same values for those expressions, so they cannot apply any meaningful distinction for ordering

Comment: [SQL Window function vs Group by](https://sundaskhalid.medium.com/sql-window-function-vs-group-by-b246d14223d2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to group, simply use a group by:

```sql
SELECT working,
       sex,
       age,
       ROUND(AVG(primaryNeeds), 1) primaryNeeds,
       ROUND(avg(WORK), 1) WORK,
       ROUND(avg(other), 1) other
FROM demography 
group by age, working, sex
```

Comment: But does "partition by" does not work for this case?

Comment: @Andrew If you group by, you reduce the number of rows and calculate the aggregation. If you use a window function, you just calculate a local aggregation without reducing the number of rows. `partition by` in windows functions is the equivalent of `group by` for group-by aggregations. If you want to keep the same number of rows, you can use the answer from @gordonlinoff

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the original rows and append the averages, then you are on the right track.  However, I think the issue is the quotes in the window clause.  And the `order by` is superfluous:

```
SELECT d.*, 
       ROUND(AVG(primaryNeeds) OVER w, 1) as primaryNeeds,
       ROUND(avg(work) OVER w, 1) as work,
       ROUND(avg(other) OVER w, 1) as other
FROM demography d
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY age, working, sex)
```

Comment: This does not work properly, in that sense, that "primaryNeeds, work, other"-columns contains average-values, calculated, without grouping.